# Haxe simple flash preloader

Tags: flash, preloader, haxe

Is there a simple way to have a preloader that just traces the percentage and then goes on to the main game? Just as simple as possible, so that I can add in the progress bar/logo animation after. I tried the thing at mindless-labs, but its really complicated, it seems kind of hackerish, I don't really understand what it's doing and it uses mochi ads which I don't want. I was going to use SamHaxe, but it won't compile on Snow Leopard. And I'd prefer one swf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to compile SamHaxe on Snow Leopard. It takes some effort, but it is possible. Here's how I did it: http://www.splashdust.net/2009/11/samhaxe-snow-leopard/